# How can i improve time or memory result in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python and so I ran into a problem: for my courses there are requirments: max time 1 sec and max memory 512Mb. The task is to find smallest palindrome in alphabetical order. minimal long for palindrome is 2.
*for example: ghghwwdkjnccjknjn here are: ghg, cc, ww, njn. We need the smallest - cc or ww - in alphabet c is in front of w (like in dictionaries). aba is in front of aca (c>b) and so on*

Here is my code:

```
s = input("")
lst = []
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1):
        p = s[i:j]
        if p == p[::-1] and len(p)>=2:
            lst.append(p)
            lst.sort()
        del p
if not lst:
    print("-1")
else:
    #lst.sort()
    print(sorted(lst, key = len)[0])
```

In this way I get 1.088s 9.89Mb and with lst.sort() moving to the end I get 0.901s 527.30Mb - both bad. How can I do it better? Thank you!

Comment: course, for example: ghghwwdkjnccjknjn here are: ghg, cc, ww, njn. We need the smallest - cc or ww - in alphabet c is in front of w (like in dictionaries)

Comment: minimal long for palindrome is 2 (requared)

Comment: so given the input you need the alphabetically earliest 'sub-squence' of the inpuit where the sub-sequence is a palnidrome.

Comment: ok - question - why are you deleting p ? That shouldn't be needed (although it wont neccessarily save much time/space)

Comment: yes, the shortest also

Comment: i just added it because it made code a bit better by memory. it does not influence on work

Comment: You are collecting all of the palindromes, and you don't need to. Find the first one, and storee it. Then find the next one - if it is earlier then store it and continue. Finding them all and then sorting is a bad idea.

Comment: Sort to the end: 0.941s 536.48Mb (without del)

Comment: how are you profiling your program ?

Comment: Tried to add: if len(p) <= len(minpalin):
                minpalin = p
                lst.append(p) to store not all palinromes, but time is still 1,072. Is a loop bad?

Comment: even doing that you are collecting them - what happens if you just record your smallest and alphabetically first one you have found; no need for a list and no need to sort.

Comment: seems like its an unsolving case for me :(

Answer (score 0):

Efficient clean implementation of all improvements mentioned below:

```
def substrings(string, length):
    for i in range(len(string) - length + 1):
        yield string[i : i+length]

def palindromes(strings):
    for string in strings:
        if string == string[::-1]:
            yield string

def best_palindrome(string):
    for length in 2, 3:
        if result := min(palindromes(substrings(string, length)), default=None):
            return result
    return -1

print(best_palindrome(input()))
```

Got accepted at Code Forces with 218 ms and 796 KB (using Python 3.7.2).

---

Perhaps the simplest modification to make it a lot more efficient is to add this as the first thing in the `j`-loop:

```
        if j - i > 3:
            break
```

That is, don't check lengths above 3. Because any longer palindrome, like abba or abcba, contains a shorter one, like bb or bcb in those cases. Since you want a shortest anyway, any longer ones are always useless.

Also, do sort only at the end, not after every append.

With those two changes, I got it accepted [at Code Forces](https://codeforces.com/problemset/gymProblem/101727/B?locale=en) (link from your comment below).

Further possible improvements:

- Don't sort, just get the minimum.
- Start `j` at `i + 2` instead of at `i + 1` and remove the `len(p)>=2` check.
- For memory reduction, don't collect everything in a list (use a set or produce the candidates in a generator).
- First try only all substrings of length 2, and only if that fails, try length 3.

Comment: @Valvoro What do you mean?

Comment: what if minimal length is 4 or 5 or 1000000?

Comment: @Valvoro Huh? klok is not a palindrome.

Comment: sorry, my bad. now i realised you are right- if we have a pali of 4 symbols - it can be cut to 2 symbols. Or we can have a pali with 3 symbols without cut.

Comment: i tried your suggestion: 1.089s. I think using many loops will be bad anyway, so the problem is deeper, but thank you for help!

Comment: @Valvoro It is very hard to believe that that didn't improve the time at all. I'm not convinced you did it correctly. This little change effectively does remove the inner loop, turning your loops part from O(n^3) to O(n).

Comment: After the line "for j in range(i + 1, len(s) + 1):" I've added: "if j-i >3:break" like you said, else we continue collecting palindromes. That seems strange to me too, no matter I change in little detailes, it doesn't matter.  I got 1.089s 21.78Mb - only memory improvment

Comment: Its sad I cant send a pic here

Comment: @Valvoro Is that problem online publicly somewhere so I could experiment with it myself?

Comment: https://codeforces.com/problemset/gymProblem/101727/B?locale=en

Comment: @Valvoro And why did you keep that secret the whole time?

Comment: It's a link for the same task, I do it on russian-competition service, but I think the check is simillar.

Comment: Sorry, just thought I was missing some small significant detail, but it seems my code itself is not relevant)

Comment: @Valvoro Was that ~1 second the actual complete runtime or was the program killed after ~1 second? My current theory is that my change did make it a lot faster, but not yet fast enough and also got killed after ~1 second.

Comment: @Valvoro See the answer update with the change that should make it fast enough and further possibilities.

Comment: @Valvoro See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) about thank-you comments and more :-)